# WHERE clause is returning result without taking subquery in account

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am using subquery to return products both from category and all the subcategories under it. Here is the sql query for it:

```
SELECT
    ca.categoryid, p.*, FLOOR(prodratingtotal/prodnumratings) AS prodavgrating, 0 AS prodgroupdiscount
FROM
    cart_categoryassociations ca, cart_products p
WHERE
    p.prodvisible=1 AND p.prodfeatured=1 AND (ca.categoryid=47 OR ca.categoryid IN (SELECT categoryid FROM cart_categories WHERE catparentid=47))
```

When I run it, it returns results based on just the `p.prodvisible=1 AND p.prodfeatured=1` part, ignoring the `(ca.categoryid=47 OR ca.categoryid IN (SELECT categoryid FROM cart_categories WHERE catparentid=47))` part.

(In other words, it brings back all featured products in the system, even if they don't belong to the categories mentioned in the subquery)

P.S: I have tried running the part in parenthesis separately and it returns correct categories.

MySQL version 5.0.8.

Comment: Which table has the alias `pi` ?

Comment: That was from a left join that I removed to simplify the query for asking here. Removed it now.
(Simplified query returns same results as the main query though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
    p.prodvisible=1 AND p.prodfeatured=1 AND (ca.categoryid=47 OR ca.categoryid IN (SELECT categoryid FROM cart_categories WHERE catparentid=47))
```

i think this is returning all the rows in cart_products matched by `p.prodvisible=1 AND p.prodfeatured=1`, for every row matched by the `(ca.categoryid=47 OR ca.categoryid IN (SELECT categoryid FROM cart_categories WHERE catparentid=47))` sub-clause.

doen't `cart_products` have some kind of foreign key to `cart_categories`?
then you might add:

`AND p.categoryid=ca.categoryid`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it must be something very simple that I keep missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM
cart_categoryassociations ca, cart_products p
```

I don't know your database structure, but shouldn't this be done with a left join instead of a full join. Is that intentional?